# найти сумму цифр целой части числа и произведение цифр дробной части числа

Tags: python

найти сумму цифр целой части числа и произведение цифр дробной части числа.

вывести исходное число, сумму и произведение так, чтобы было удобно для чтения.

Ps: исходное число - 405,

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну надо найти  -  найдите. Если что при этом будет не получаться - задайте вопросы, вам помогут. А вот решать за ваш ваши школьные задачки тут не будут - увы, таковы правила этого сайта, с которыми вы скорее всего не ознакомились.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Пожалуйста

```
n = input()
s = str(n)
letsGo = 0
proizved = 1
summa = 0
for i in s:
    if letsGo == 1:
        proizved *= int(i)
    if i == ".":
        letsGo = 1
    if letsGo == 0:
        summa += int(i)
print("Сумма: ",summa)
print("Произведение: ",proizved)
```

Comment: Вот зачем подсказывать решения с ошибкой??? Специально, что-бы "наказать" ТС???: Вы сами свой скрипт проверяли? Если проверяли, то какой результат он выдал ДАЖЕ на пример, который приведен в вопросе?? На числе 405 ? Если не проверяли, то подскажу - ответ вашего скрипта "Сумма: 9 Произведение: 1". А теперь внимание, вопрос: каково должно быть произведение цифр дробной части этого числа и почему оно у вас равно 1?